# Spring security OAuth redirect endpoint not found

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, java-ee-7

I have added Spring Security to an existing JEE application to add OAuth to the application.
The security configuration is set to protect the REST API, and that part seems to work fine.
When the UI requests a protected URL, the response contains a redirect to 'oauth2/authorize/keycloak'.

But that's where the story ends, since the request to 'oauth2/authorize/keycloak' itself returns a 404.

I am pretty out of date with spring security (have used it the last time with Spring applications about 8 years ago) and I have no idea where I am supposed to find the implementation of the endpoint 'oauth2/authorize/keycloak' in order to figure out what is missing or wrong in my setup.

The relevant part of my dependency tree looks as follows:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.mycompany.auth:authentication-sso-configuration:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.nimbusds:content-type:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile (version selected from constraint [1.3.1,2.3])
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:8.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider:jar:5.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-messaging-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-storage-api:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |        \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-impl:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.66:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.8:compile
```

And this is the configuration for OAuth

```
# OAuth2 login manifest
oauth2Login:
  authorizationCode:
    authorizationUri: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
    scope:
      - "openid"
      - "finx"
    redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
    tokenUri: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    userInfoUri: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
    jwkSetKeyUri: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
    registrationId: "keycloak"
    clientId: "finx_oauth2"
    clientSecret:
      vaultType: PLAIN_TEXT
      secret: "my-secret"
    clientName: "FinX"
    entryPoints:
      - pathMatcher: "/ledger-api/**"
      - pathMatcher: "/ledger-api-internal/**"
      - pathMatcher: "/ledger-api-ui/**"
# OAuth2 resource server
oauth2ResourceServer:
  keySetUri: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
  pathMatchers:
    - "/api/**"
    - "/orchestration-api/**"
```

I have been digging through the spring source code in order to find the implementation of the endpoint 'oauth2/authorize/keycloak', but this is not an easy task.

So looking for someone who can help me with some pointers on what could be missing/wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the OAuth 2.0 Login Page is auto-generated by the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`.
The login page for a client defaults to this: `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI + "/{registrationId}"`. As per your configuration, `registrationId: "keycloak"`, this means (`/oauth2/authorization/keycloak`).

Please check your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration. Try to override the default login page by configuring oauth2Login().loginPage() and (optionally) oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint().baseUri().

The following listing shows an example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/login/oauth2")
            ...
            .authorizationEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/login/oauth2/authorization")
                ....
}
```

Please check [OAuth 2.0 Login - Advanced Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-login-page) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Vijay. This was the information I was looking for.
Seems like the problem was in my configuration. Adding the following to 'oauth2Login.authorizationCode.entryPoints' did the trick

      - pathMatcher: "/oauth2/**"
        anonymous: true
      - pathMatcher: "/login/**"
        anonymous: true
      - pathMatcher: "/logout/**"
        anonymous: true

Comment: Pretty strange, because if that was the problem, I would have rather expected some kind of endless loop or stack overflow error, rather than a 404 if the problem was due to path '/oauth2/**' being protected.